# select distinct values from JSON using django-mysql

Tags: mysql, django

I'm using [this](https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/json_field.html) library and my model looks like this:

```
class PhoneTest(Model):
    data = JSONField()
```

My JSON obj looks something like this (in a real obj there are way more fields):

{
    "deviceStatus": true,
    "officerCode": 123456,
    "imei": 123456789123456
}

For instance, I want to get a list of all officerCodes. How do I do that ? All I've tried so far has not worked. For example this did not:

```
tests = PhoneTests.objects.all()
tests.distinct('data__mOfficerCode')
```

It gives me the following error:

```
NotSupportedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend
```

But it's because I'm using this new library, not the native django mysql backend. What are possible workarounds?

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use values_list method

```
PhoneTests.objects.all().values_list('data__mOfficerCode').distinct()
```